# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <>

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial wherein I have created a directory structure like this:

```
└── address_book
    ├── proto
    │   ├── addressbook.proto
    │   └── addressbook_pb2.py
    └── src
        └── write.py
```

*write.py* content:

```
import os
import sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
                  os.path.dirname(__file__), 
                  os.pardir)
)
sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT)

from address_book.proto import addressbook_pb2 as ab
```

So now when I try to execute write.py, I run into following error:

> (venv) 15:53:32:~/Desktop/work/mbip/protobufs % python
> address_book/src/write.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "address_book/src/write.py", line 10, in 
> from address_book.proto import addressbook_pb2 as ab ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'address_book'

Comment: Adjusting `sys.path` inside a Python script or module is not recommended, unless you know what you're doing. You should set PYTHONPATH outside of the script/module, in your shell or directly on the command line for example.

Comment: just see in terminal from PROJECT_ROOT are you able to import the module or not

Comment: @sahasrara62 I'm able to import from the terminal:
```(venv) 16:03:41:~/Desktop/work/mbip/protobufs % python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Dec 21 2020, 15:06:04) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from address_book.proto import addressbook_pb2 as ab
>>> address_book = ab.AddressBook()
>>> type(address_book)
<class 'addressbook_pb2.AddressBook'>
```

Comment: @9769953 thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep a note of it. That seemed to work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
import os
import sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
                  os.path.dirname(__file__), 
                  os.pardir)
)

# print(sys.path)
sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT)
# print(sys.path)

#you don't need the parent dir again since you already added it to the path

from proto import addressbook_pb2 as ab
```